# jquery resizable incorrect width

Tags: jquery

i wanna resize the right element "w" and fit the size of the middle element,so that the total width of both does not change. What i tried to do is to add/substract the px on the middle element on resize. The info div shows the correct middle width while resizing, but the visible middle div´s width is not the same as shown in info div. The same method works width resize "e", but not "w". Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/perea1/2j6L9/9/
Btw, i dont like to use the resizeReverse plugin.

```
.wrapper {
    width:300px;
    height:80px;
    background-color:#ccc;
     }
.left {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:80px;
    background-color:yellow;
     }
.middle {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:80px;
    background-color:green;
     }
.right {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:80px;
        background-color:blue;
     }

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left"></div>   
    <div class="middle"></div>   
    <div class="right"></div>   
    </div>  
    <div class="info1"></div> 
    <div class="info2"></div> 

$(".right").resizable({
    autoHide: true,
    handles: "w",
    start: function (event, ui) {
        startw = $(this).width();
        midw = $(".middle").width();
    },
    resize: function (event, ui) {
        var resw = $(this).width();
        var neww = startw - resw;

        $(".middle").css("width", ui.originalSize.width + neww);
        $(".info1").text(resw);
        $(".info2").text(midw + neww);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ive added positon 0 on the right element, now it works

```
$(this).css("left","0");
```